# Transfer ERC20 a wallet to another

Tags: contract-development, truffle, erc-20, contract-deployment, openzeppelin

Well, I need the following help.
I'm developing a game, and in this game my ERC20 coin will have by default 1billion of the token in a wallet called "Rewards".
That way, my contract for that currency when I implement it will automatically mine 1billion for the "Rewards" address, so far, ok.

At some point I need to withdraw coins from my wallet (rewards) and move to another wallet (players).

For this situation I found an alternative, which I don't believe is the safest, because it's about adding in the frontend of my game the option for web3 to access my wallet (rewards) through PrivateKey, but as I said, this transaction by if it were handled on the frontend, my privateKey would be exposed and anyone could steal my account.

That said, what did I do?
I created in my contract a method called "withdrawRewards", my idea is basically to do the "transfer" process that the ERC20 contract already has, the only difference that would not go through approve, and I would be validating based on a signature that I would be generating using the ECDSA lib, but what's the problem with that?
The problem is that the variable "_balances" is private and I can't access it, even though the contract is extending the ERC20.

My question is, how can I do this in the best and safest way possible?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Pausable, AccessControl, ERC20Burnable, Ownable  {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    mapping (address => uint256) private _nonces;
    address private sigAddres;

    //wallet 1kkk
    // address public rewardsAddr          = address(0x59D6fcF2e8210cDC481389c21f2D6); 
    address public rewardsAddr          = address(0x961aCa5d56EfD5971aF8F);     
    //Tax address
    address public taxAddr   = address(0x90475bB7492F3c5949475FDD1);

    //tax buy/sell initial 5%     
    uint256 private transferFees = 5;
    bool private initializedFees = true; 

    constructor() ERC20("TOKEN COIN", "TOKEN") {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        // _mint(rewardsAddr, 1000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
        _mint(owner(), 1000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);                
    }

    /**
    * @dev Fallback function if ether is sent to address 
    **/
    receive() external payable {
        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    }

    /**    
     * @dev overrides transfer for tokenomics
     */
    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual override{
        // require(tokenDenylist[msg.sender] == false, "Address in deny list");
        require(amount > 0, "ERC20: transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");                

        if(hasFees(sender, recipient)){
           
           uint256 feesTotal = amount.mul(transferFees).div(100);
           amount = amount - feesTotal;
           
           //wallet transfer fees
           super._transfer(sender, taxAddr, feesTotal);
        }

       super._transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function withdrawRewards(address _player, uint256 _amount, uint256 _nonce, bytes memory _signature)
    public virtual isValidSignature(_player, _amount, _nonce, _signature) returns(bool){
        
        uint256 rewardsBalance = _balances[rewardsAddr];
        require(rewardsBalance >= _amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        if(_nonces[_player] >= _nonce){
            revert("Withdraw already used");
        }
        unchecked {
            _balances[rewardsAddr] = rewardsBalance - _amount;
        }
        _balances[_player] += _amount;

        _nonces[_player] = _nonce;

        emit Transfer(rewardsAddr, _player, _amount);

        return true;
    }
    
    function hasFees(address sender, address recipient) private view returns(bool){
        if(initializedFees == true && 
            (transferFees > 0) 
            && (sender != taxAddr)  
            // && (sender != holdersAddr)              
            && (sender != owner()) 
            && (recipient != taxAddr)
            // && (recipient != holdersAddr)
            && (recipient != rewardsAddr)){
                return true;
            }
            
            return false;
    }

    function pause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
        _unpause();
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount);        
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    modifier isValidSignature(address _player, uint256 _amount, uint256 _nonce, bytes memory _signature) {
        bytes32 message = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_player, _amount, _nonce));
        assert(ECDSA.recover(message, _signature) == sigAddres);        
        _;
    }

    function setSig(address _sig) public onlyOwner{
        sigAddres = _sig;
    }

    function updateAddrFees(uint _fee) public onlyOwner{
        transferFees = _fee;
    }

    function initFees(bool _startFee) public onlyOwner{
        initializedFees = _startFee;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the signature part I'd use something like [EIP-2612 permit – 712-signed approvals](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612).

For the rewards part you have to use `_transfer`. If you want to skip the fee related changes you could call the parent function with `ERC20._transfer(..)`.

```
function withdrawRewards(address _player, uint256 _amount, uint256 _nonce, bytes memory _signature)
public virtual isValidSignature(_player, _amount, _nonce, _signature) returns(bool){
    
    uint256 rewardsBalance = balanceOf(rewardsAddr);
    require(rewardsBalance >= _amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    require(_nonces[_player] < _nonce, "Withdraw already used");

    ERC20._transfer(rewardsAddr, _player, _amount);

    _nonces[_player] = _nonce;

    emit Transfer(rewardsAddr, _player, _amount);

    return true;
}
```